# yield return method optimized away when it shouldn't be

Tags: c#, ienumerable, compiler-optimization, yield-return

I've stumbled upon a test problem of my library where a `yield return` gets optimized for reasons I don't understand.

Proof of concept code:

```
static IEnumerable<int> Sample(int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) yield return i;
}
static IEnumerable<int> ForEach(IEnumerable<int> items, Action<int> action)
{
    foreach (int item in items) { action(item); yield return item; }
}
static void After(IEnumerable<int> items, Action action)
{
    action();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int item = -1;
    After(ForEach(Sample(10), v => item = v), () => Console.WriteLine(item));
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I expect the output to be `9` then `9`.

The actual output is `-1` then `-1`.

The initialization of `IEnumerable`s at `Sample` and `ForEach` is optimized away, and as a side effect `item` inside `Main` is never changed.

Why hasn't `Sample` been iterated at `ForEach`?

Am I *really* required to iterate `items` at `After`?

If yes, why have the optimization be so deep that even the iteration at `ForEach` is halted until provoked, making the output `-1` then `9` possible too?

Comment: If you don't iterate the items, the `ForEach` method will never be called at all. You could do `ForEach(...).ToList()` for example.

Comment: Your `after` method never invokes `items.GetEnumerator`. Remember that `yield return` is **lazily-evaluated**.

Comment: Unrelated, but there's a built-in `Enumerable.Range` method for generating simple sequences.

Comment: Dai, read the first question - why hasn't `Sample` been iterated at `ForEach`?

Comment: @Luka967 because the `ForEach` method is also a lazily-evaluated state machine function. Simply by using `yield return` your method is rewritten by the compiler to be lazily-evaluated, that includes both `after` and your `ForEach`.

Comment: @Dai Or to put it all that in four words, it had deferred execution. I knew enumerables were lazily evaluated but I didn't know optimization went so far deferred execution exists. Oh well, thanks for the downvote on a sensible question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` objects have deferred execution which means they are executed when they are accessed for iterating. When we start iterating or materialize an object of it to a `List<T>` or `Array` then it's actually invoked.

If you add `ToList()` call to your `ForEach` method, you will see the expected output:

```
After(ForEach(Sample(10), v => item = v).ToList(), () => Console.WriteLine(item));
```

As you seen you materialized the `ForEach()` method's resultant `IEnumerable` it will invoke the `Sample()` too and execute.

You can modify your methods like following to see when actually the method got invoked:

```
static IEnumerable<int> Sample(int count)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sample Invoked");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        yield return i;
}

static IEnumerable<int> ForEach(IEnumerable<int> items, Action<int> action)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ForEach Invoked:");
    foreach (int item in items)
    {
        action(item);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

and then call it in this way:

```
int item = -1;
After(ForEach(Sample(10), v => item = v), () => Console.WriteLine(item));
Console.WriteLine(item);
    
After(ForEach(Sample(10), v => item = v).ToList(), () => 
Console.WriteLine(item));
Console.WriteLine(item);
```

and the output is:

> -1
>
> -1
>
> ForEach Invoked:
>
> Sample Invoked
>
> 9
>
> 9

See the [Fiddle DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4BEz8e) to observe it in action.

Comment: I knew `IEnumerable`s were evaluated lazily, but I've never heard about deferred execution for C#. Thanks for the explanation!